# email: Where does the datetime stamp in the From_ line of an mbox mail message stem from?

Tags: email, file-format

I am currently working on a program converting mailbox files from an old, tenex based mail format to mbox. The tenex mailbox format has separator lines like the mbox format (the latter is called the From_ line),

tenex:

```
 7-Feb-86 21:41:21-EST,1925;000000000000
```

mbox:

```
From mail@example.com Fri Feb 07 14:20:00 1986
```

but due to a lack of documentation, the origin of the datetime stamp in the separator line of a "tenex formatted" file is obscure.

Hence, when transforming a message from the tenex to mbox format, I used the datetime stamp from date-header field for constructing the From_ line for the mbox formatted message, not the one in the separator line of the tenex formatted file.

But [RFC4155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155), an attempt to describe "the" mbox format (there are actually several different formats) and supply a kind of standard for this file format, states:

> Each message begins with a separator line that identifies the message
> sender, and also identifies the date and time at which the message was
> received by the final recipient (either the last-hop system in the
> transfer path, or the system which serves as the recipient's
> mailstore).

Hence, I am in doubt that my approach using the datetime stamp from the date header field is correct.

But, without having the transport envelope, from where can I get the actual datetime stamp of the final recipient receiving the message? Is this the datetime stamp in the last entry of the of Received header field(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "From_" line is written by the `mail.local` program (originally called `mail` in the 7th Edition Unix) with the timestamp being the actual time when the message is written to the mailbox.

I.e. "*the date and time at which the message was received by the final recipient*" is actually the time the message was written into the recipient's mailbox file, which is exactly when the final recipient "receives" the message.

The code for writing the initial separator line in an "mbox" file, prior to the message content, is quite literally:

```
    time(&tval);
    fprintf(fp, "From %s %s", from, ctime(&tval));
```

So, if the timestamp in the separator line in TENEX mailboxes is also the "received" time (which is what the [Pine Technical Notes](https://archive.org/details/tech-notes) say about it:  *The time in the header is the time that message was written to the folder.*), so then you just need to reformat it.  These timestamps have exactly the same meaning.

Comment: Thx! Where can I find the Pine doc you quote?

Comment: This is not the canonical location, I don't think, but this is where I found it most recently:  https://web.pa.msu.edu/reference/pine-tech-notes/low-level.html#format

Comment: very worthful resource. thx!

Comment: So, does this answer all of your questions?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Perhaps you can accept my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

> Where can I get the actual datetime stamp of the final recipient receiving the message? Is this the datetime stamp in the last entry of the of Received header field(s)?

In a typical MTA delivery situation the leading From line (without a colon) is the delivery timestamp. If you don't have that then there are some other options to consider. It might be recorded by the receiving MTA in an Envelope header (I can't remember the exact detail). Or if you trust the Received header fields it should be the top-most (first) one. Failing that the Date field should give a reasonable approximation unless you're expecting seriously slow mail delivery, such as UUCP over dialup.

Comment: I guess that I do not have the envelope data if I only own the mailbox file, and have no access to the MTA. Correct? The messages I am working with stem from a bulletin board on the lisp language and the dates in the examples are from real messages exchanged via the ARPANET in the mid-to-late eighties (so, we can assume that the machines involved are recycled meanwhile, building iphone parts or similar ;-> ; Therefore, no access to the MTA. Interestingly, the discrepancies between the datetime stamps in the "most-recent" Received field and the Date field range from 1 or two minutes up to

Comment: several hours. I guess that the MIT servers and other machines had a connectivity which does not explain the long end of the range at that time. Nevertheless, I think the best approximation under these circumstances is yielded when using the information from the uppermost Received field.

Comment: 1980s? Then yes you could easily be dealing with UUCP type links and long delays. RFC822 was valid back then. Much of it is almost impenetrable but you might glean an extra nugget or two about received and envelope dates